# RuntimeException: Unable to start activity (Android)

Tags: android, runtimeexception, start-activity

I am working on an app and am getting a strange error. Two out of the three devices that have been used so far to test the app work perfectly when the log in button is tapped and a new activity is started. The two phones that work are both running on Ice Cream Sandwhich and the third phone (the one that is giving me trouble) is running on JellyBean.

When the log in button is tapped using the JellyBean phone this is what happens.

**Java (Register Page)**

```
           // Register button
            TextView main_body_register_button = new TextView(this);
             main_body_register_button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.register_btn);
             main_body_register_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // Post to the MySQL database
                        class sendtask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
                            protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
                                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://website.com/register.php");  
                                        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
                                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("number", ""+main_body_phone_input.getText().toString()));

                                            try {
                                                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            } 
                                            try {
                                                httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                                            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                                return "";
                            }
                                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                                    if (main_body_phone_input.getText().toString().compareTo("012-345-6789")==0) {
                                        // Phone number: Empty
                                        Intent base_account_register = new Intent(base_account_register.this,base_account_register.class);
                                        startActivity(base_account_register);
                                    } else if (main_body_phone_input.getText().toString().compareTo("012-345-6789")!=0) {
                                        // Switch to main page
                                        Intent TellATextActivity = new Intent(base_account_register.this,TellATextActivity.class);
                                         ownAddress  = ""+main_body_phone_input.getText().toString();
                                        startActivity(TellATextActivity);
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                            new sendtask().execute("Registration form");
                        // End
                    }
             });
           // END
```

**Java (OnCreate TellATextActivity)**

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Global variables
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    final String ownAddress  = bundle.getString("session_number");

       // MAIN
       TextView main_message = new TextView(this);
            // Select and parse the most recent message
            Uri uriSMS = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
            Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMS, null, null, null, null);

            // EDIT IN          
            if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()) {
             do {
              // Inflate your data
             } while (cur.moveToNext());
            }
             cur.close()
            // END

            // EDIT OUT
            cur.moveToNext();
            cur.moveToNext();
            // END

            String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("body"));
            String add = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
             reply_address = "" +add;
            String time = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("date"));
            String protocol = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("protocol"));
            String contactName = "";

            Uri personUri = Uri.withAppendedPath( ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(add));
                Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(personUri, new String[] { PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME }, null, null, null );  
                    if( c.moveToFirst() ) {
                        int nameIndex = c.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME);  
                        contactName = c.getString(nameIndex);
                    }
                    c.close();
                    cur.close();
            String out = "";
            Date d = new Date(Long.valueOf(time));
            // End

            // Determine status of message
            if (protocol == null)
                out = ""+body;
            else 
                out = ""+body;
            // End

            // Create output
            main_message.setHeight(400);
            main_message.setWidth(510);
            main_message.setPadding(10,15,10,0);
            main_message.setTextSize(23);
            main_message.setTextColor(Color.rgb(100,100,100));
            main_message.setText(out);
            // End
        // END

        TextView bottom_reply = new TextView(this);
         bottom_reply.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.reply);
         bottom_reply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 // Compose a reply
                 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
                 intent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" +reply_address));
                 intent.putExtra("compose_mode", true);
                 startActivity(intent);
             }
         });
        // END

     }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <activity
        android:name=".TellATextActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android-dir/mms-sms" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**Crash Report**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{tellatext.sms.app/tellatext.sms.app.TellATextActivity}: 
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2049)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2083)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1233)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4697)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1
at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:407)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:114)
at tellatext.sms.app.TellATextActivity.onCreate(TellATextActivity.java:82)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4539)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2013)
... 11 more
```

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction here? I have exhausted all of my options and need someone else's perspective on the issue.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't want to annoy but try to define classes not into listeners :) (it's not javascript). Did you get crash on start? Did you try to debug?

Comment: Please, post the code of the method onCreate ofTellATextActivity. And indicate the which line is the line 82.

Comment: Please look under "JAVA (OnCreate TellATextActivity)" to see my OnCreate method. I just posted it. Would anyone be able to explain why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was occuring when someone was using the app with less than 3 text messages in their inbox. By moving the inbox cursor to a spot without a text message the app as crashing because the spot didn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your code you are requesting a cursor item from slot 1 thinking that it is the first slot. Incorrect. Cusors are 0 indexed and as such, 0 is the first slot. Try changing your start index to 0.

Edit example:

```
Cursor cur = null; // Your query not null

if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        // Inflate your data
    } while (cur.moveToNext());
}
cur.close()
```

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at my revision? I posted the OnCreate method. Where would I make the changes to the cursor index?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but it is probably that section where you call `cur.moveToFirst()` twice sequentially. Lines 13 and 14 in your `onCreate(Bundle)` method.

Comment: If that is the problem would you have a solution?

Comment: @PeterMerrill Not call it, let alone twice? Why are you calling `Cursor.moveToNext()` there anyway? If you need to shift rows to find what you are looking for, your query is wrong. It's also better to start query inflation of the data with something like what is in my edit.

Comment: Thank you. I used that in the app and it still crashed.

Comment: @PeterMerrill Is the stack trace different? Could you also update you onCreate method with what you have changed?

Comment: Updated. Please see // EDIT OUT. I had to remove Cursor cur = null; because it wanted me to rename the cursor. I also tried entering in what you see in // EDIT OUT twice. I tried removing the cursor close too. Nothing helped.

Comment: `Cursor cur` wasn't suppose to equal null. It was to be assigned by your query, I was just lazy and didn't copy your query in. As for the rest, I'm not sure what you saying.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't in this part. It's actually your onCreate method, at line 82. If you go there and change your 1 to a 0 as suggested by Aedon, then all will work.